# Why is expires header response set to future date with max-age=0?

Tags: firefox, http-headers, google-cloud-storage

I noticed an odd behaviour with the *expires* property in the HTTP response header sent by Google Cloud Storage.
Though, the cache-control is defined with **max-age:0** for the file in the metadata (as visible in the screenshot), the *expires* property is set to a date one year in the future (second screenshot). Why is this date set to the future?

[image: File on cloud storage - Metadata]

[image: HTTP response header]

The problematic thing with this behaviour is, that the most recent Firefox versions (v.77 and v.78) seem to interprete the *expires* property, though it is stated in the documentation, that it will not if max-age is defined (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires). For livestream video playback with HLS, this behaviour leads to buffering after short time, because the manifest is cached by the browser. There is already a bug report on mozilla@bugzilla on this behaviour (see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1648075).

---

**Update**

Further investigation showed, that Firefox is not the problem in this case, they just changed the interpretation of the header properties and stick to the [documentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2) since v.77, where '=' is defined as needed character, not ':'. Obviously, other browsers (and FF up to v.76) interprete it also correctly with ':'.

Therefore, in our case the issue needs to be solved inside the service writing the files to our GCS.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say *why* Google Cloud Storages is doing this. Perhaps the `Expires` is a default, while the `Cache-Control` is used for custom user settings? More likely, it's just an oversight.

The important point is that this behavior is allowed, and would be harmless with compliant browsers due to the [explicit precedence](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.3) of `max-age`:

> If a response includes a `Cache-Control` field with the `max-age` directive (Section 5.2.2.8), a recipient MUST ignore the `Expires` field.

So the real issue is that Firefox is not conforming to the HTTP specification. Hopefully [that bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1648075) will be fixed soon.